# Failed to initialize TLS context

Tags: openssl, tls1.2, bloomberg, fix-protocol, stunnel

I have installed stunnel version stunnel-5.43.tar.gz on linux server. after assign certification path and `stunnel.conf` file, my stunnel is not able to start due to **tlsversion** .
see this is my stunnel.conf:

```
[abc] 
client = yes cert = /usr/local/etc/stunnel/cert.pem key = /usr/local/etc/stunnel/key.pem CAfile = /usr/local/etc/stunnel/Cert.pem sslVersion = TLSv1.2 accept = 127.0.0.1:5001 connect = x.x.x.x:port
```

I am getting this error while starting stunnel:

```
[root@test stunnel]# stunnel #Certification loaded here  >Loading certificate from file: /usr/local/etc/stunnel/cert.pem >Certificate loaded from file: /usr/local/etc/stunnel/cert.pem >Loading private key from file: /usr/local/etc/stunnel/key.pem >Insecure file permissions on /usr/local/etc/stunnel/key.pem >#Getting here >SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file: B080074: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch >Service [abc]: Failed to initialize TLS context
```

> Service [abc]: Failed to initialize TLS context

Comment: >[root@test stunnel]# stunnel
#Certification loaded here

>Loading certificate from file: /usr/local/etc/stunnel/cert.pem
>Certificate loaded from file: /usr/local/etc/stunnel/cert.pem
>Loading private key from file: /usr/local/etc/stunnel/key.pem
>Insecure file permissions on /usr/local/etc/stunnel/key.pem
>#Getting here
>SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file: B080074: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
>Service [abc]: Failed to initialize TLS context

Comment: Stunnel process is not started due to tls version

Comment: you must add detailed information to your question instead of pasting here.:)

Comment: I have installed stunnel version stunnel-5.43.tar.gz on linux server 
after assign certification path and stunnel.conf file my stunnel is not able to start due to tlsversion

see this is my stunnel.conf 
[abc]
client = yes
cert = /usr/local/etc/stunnel/cert.pem
key = /usr/local/etc/stunnel/key.pem
CAfile = /usr/local/etc/stunnel/Cert.pem
sslVersion = TLSv1.2
accept = 127.0.0.1:5001
connect = x.x.x.x:port

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Isn’t the error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your private key file (/usr/local/etc/stunnel/key.pem) has permissions set to 600 with:

```
chmod 600 /usr/local/etc/stunnel/key.pem
```

From the stunnel manual:

> The stunnel.pem file contains your key (private data) and certificate (public data). In order for stunnel to start automatically without requiring a password, the key is created without a password. This means that anyone who can read this file can compromise your SSL security. **This file must be readable only by root, or the user who runs stunnel**.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:  https://github.com/square/ghostunnel

```
bin/ghostunnel client  --listen localhost:8443 --target fixbeta-rhub.bloomberg.com:8228 --keystore keys/fixbeta-rhub.bloomberg.com.p12     --cacert keys/CACerts.pem   --override-server-name=fixbeta.bloomberg.com
```